# Forward message to private group with pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

How can I forward message to private group ?

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler
app = Client("my_account")

def message_forward(client, message):
        message.forward("R1u9aqYQDbw4NThk")


message_forward_handler = MessageHandler(message_forward)
app.add_handler(message_forward_handler)
app.run()
```

Comment: You need to be a member of the group you want to forward to. Then you can use the `chat_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join that particular private group and then obtain its chat_id, then simply pass it into `message.forward`.
Also, out of context, you can use the decorator `@app.on_message()` instead of registering the handler manually.